# Textures not showing up in rendered mode

Tags: texturing

I just finished modeling my first 3D model while following a tutorial and I got to texturing. I did flat colors just to start out, but (and this may have been where I went wrong, but it wouldn't get it to work any other way) I did my painting on the checkered material instead.

I saved my texturing image but the textures never load in any mode other than texture paint mode with solid viewport shading. Nothing shows up at all in rendered mode. I can't figure out where I went wrong because I'm new at Blender. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Could you upload your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? I'm not to familiar with Blender Render Engine, so it's hard to tell without fiddling with it.

Comment: @LukeD I uploaded the file, let me know if I should add the texture file to my post.

Comment: It will be helpful :) You can pack texture by: File > External Data > Pack All into .blend file.

Comment: I updated the file link, let me know if it didn't work and I'll fix it as soon as I can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem existed because of multiple materials assigned to object. Which most of them was **Cycles materials**.

First step is go to **Object Mode** and in **Material tab** delete any unnecessary materials and leave only the one you will use (*"character"* at the bottom of the list).

[image: 1]

Next switch to the **Texture tab** and check preview to **Texture** (not needed but helpful), select image *"checkered"* and check **View as Render**.

[image: 2]

Everything should now work just fine.

Comment: I fixed it! Thank you so much for your help, it shows up in render mode! Just a quick question, is it normal for no texture to appear in object mode?

Comment: I'm not sure why, because I don't use blender render at all, but it seems to be some kind of override by multiple materials (cycles) which blender render can't render and for sure view as rendered not checked was a factor for texture.